# Best Practices for Creating CDF e-textbook

Tags: cdf-format

I attended a talk given by Eric Schulz a few years ago.  It was similar to his talk "Sharing Wisdom Gained from Publishing a CDF Ebook" given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUobpMR04Kw).  I am Math instructor and have been creating textbook-like CDF lectures in Mathematica for my students.  I have absorbed quite a bit from his videos and am now able to reproduce a CDF textbook that looks and works like his.

I've created palettes to help aid in the creating process, autoinputreplacments to cut down on writing time, stylesheets to emulate textbooks, and different types of automation to push information to all notebooks, etc...

I'm interested in learning more from other people on best practices for e-text creation using Mathematica.  Eric is a wealth of knowledge but is extremely busy working on his textbooks.

Does anyone know of any other resources they are willing to share that could aid a person creating a modern CDF etext?  I know this is broad topic... however, I would not have known even where to start without the the multiple ideas given in the video above.  I know there is still so much I don't know.  Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should put this in Mathematica Meta or the Mathematica forum.  Please advise.

Comment: Meta is about the site so your comment is a good question for meta. Your main question fits community.wolfram.com as it is more discussion friendly. It is indeed too broad/opinion based for the main site, otoh we know such questions already exist and are well. So you could try, can't promise it won't be closed and you won't face critique. Also, don't say I sent you there :) p.s. make sure to add more links because there are many related topics online and here too. Add more precise description of what features you are interested in. People appreciate effort put in the question.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain, Wolfram is releasing a CDF Player for iOS very soon (I think they're doing beta for it), it might be worth developing your CDF with that  in mind (i.e. cross testing it on that platform during development) as that way students can easily access it from their iPads and iPhones.

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need to overthink it though. By default, Mathematica has a lot of tools for nice word processing, particularly in the contxt of technical content with its typesetting. Use the default styles to structure it, or change them as needed. If you had more specific questions I'd be happy to help, but for general usage i just open a notebook and go, with text cells, input cells, manipulates, section cells, etc.....